# swift optional generic type and nested optional unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift, generics, option-type, key-value-observing

I've got this piece of code

```
class MyObject<T> {

    func start(_ value: T?) {
        if let value = value {
            doSomething(value)
        }
    }

    func doSomething(_ value: T) {
        print(value)
    }
}

MyObject<String>().start("some")
// prints "some"

MyObject<String?>().start(nil)
// doesn't print anything
```

I need `doSomething()` to be called for every valid value passed to `start()`. And when `T` is already an optional type like `String?`, then `nil` is a valid value.

Do I need to write two versions of `start()` in extensions of `MyObject` with conditions on the type of `T`? And how to do it?

Comment: Why would you need something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your `start` function take a non-optional `T` and just always call `doSomething` instead of trying to unwrap it first.  This would only allow you to call `start(nil)` if `T` itself was an optional type:

```
class MyObject<T> {

    func start(_ value: T) {
        doSomething(value)
    }

    func doSomething(_ value: T) {
        print(value)
    }
}

MyObject<String>().start("some")
// prints "some"

MyObject<String?>().start(nil)
// prints "nil"
```

If you want to leave the parameter to `start` as optional then your original code will actually work, but you need to change the way you are passing your value in your second example.

Since `T` is `String?`, the parameter in your method is of type `String??` and passing a nil `String??` is different then passing one with a `String?` that happens to contain `nil`.

If you call it as:

```
MyObject<String?>().start(.some(nil))
```

or

```
let string: String? = nil
MyObject<String?>().start(string)
```

Then it will print "nil"

Answer (score 0):

Since let value = value fails with the second input you need to handle that case separately.

```
func start(_ value: T?) {
    if let value = value {
        doSomething(value)
    }
    else
    {
        print("nil input")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! However, what I meant is that I need `doSomething:` to be called for every valid value passed to `-start:`. And when `T == String?`, then "nil" is a valid value. A workaround in the `-start:` method won't fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

In case value is nil, when you unwrap the value will not enter in the if statement. Instead, you can do this:

```
class MyObject<T> {

    func start(_ value: T?) {
        if let value = value {
            doSomething(value)
        } else {
            print("nil")
        }
    }

    func doSomething(_ value: T) {
        print(value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Optional in Swift is just a generic enum that have two cases:

```
enum Optional<T> {
    case some(T)
    case none
}
```

For example `String?` is the same thing of `Optional<String>`.

If you declare `MyObject<String?>` basically you're creating this `MyObject<Optional<String>>`, so your concrete `start` method will be

```
func start(_ value: Optional<Optional<String>>) { ... }
```

This means that if you call it like `start(nil)`, the whole object will be of course nil and the `if let` will fail.
You can however call that function in this way

```
MyObject<String?>().start(Optional.some(Optional.none))
MyObject<String?>().start(.some(.none)) // -> shorter version with type inference
```

Basically now the outer optional exists and the unwrap works, but the inner one is `nil`.

However I still can't understand why would you need to do something like that